# Asset Precompile on Amazon Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, precompile

I installed [locomotivecms](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/install-engine) app on a small amazon linux instance. I ran following to precompile the assets:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It's been like half an hour and the assets are still precompiling. Following is what I have on the terminal so far:

```
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-09-15-88 locomotivecms]$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
which: no convert in (/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
which: no identify in (/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/locomotivecms/public/assets
cp -rp /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/locomotive-tinymce-rails-3.5.8.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/tinymce /home/ec2-user/locomotivecms/public/assets
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/locomotivecms/public/assets
cp -rp /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/locomotive-aloha-rails-0.23.2.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/aloha /home/ec2-user/locomotivecms/public/assets
which: no convert in (/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
which: no identify in (/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

Do the which commands mean that time is being spent finding the rake executable for each file that is getting precompiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you do not have imagemagick installed.

Depending on your distro, it should be either `sudo yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel` or `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`.

You can test it whether it installed successfully by issuing the commands `convert` or `identify`.

However, the documentation recommends that your precompile on your own local machine, not on the remote server. Meaning, you issue `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on your own machine first. That would avoid having to precompile on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned Imagemagick was missing. After installing it , I no longer see the which: no convert, which: no identify messages.